# Is it possible to use Windows 7 with B550/X570 motherboards and Ryzen 9 CPUs?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, cpu, motherboard

I understand that official support of Windows 7 ended a few years ago.

However, I'm interested to know if any manufacturers (or users) have released fully-working drivers for B550/X570 motherboards or the Ryzen 9 CPUs like the 5600X or 5900X.

I would like to know if it's possible to replace my faulty Windows 7 hardware with modern, high-performance hardware without having to upgrade to Windows 8 or 10.

I can't find reliable information about this anywhere. If I ask on other websites I am simply downvoted, insulted, or ridiculed for daring to ask about Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that more and more devices will lack drivers for Windows 7. The system will generally work, but Windows 10 graphics drivers and drivers for other devices may not work on Windows 7 leaving you with a system that is not fully utilising all it has in it. There is no "reliable" answer because it depends entirely on how much functionality you need and your definition of "works".

Comment: My question was closed (unfairly IMO) but I managed to do this eventually. I used a Windows 7 ISO which was slipstreamed with the latest USB 3 drivers and Windows updates and was able to install on a B550/AMD system just fine. The ISO came from the helpful people at Reddit's `/r/legacywindows`, now moved to `forum.eclipse.cx`.

Comment: I find it very concerning that people WANT to do this... Knowing the OS is end of life for over a year already. Without proper updates and security patches, this OS just keeps getting more and more dangerous to use every day.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You might not be able to use all of the usb ports if you are on asrock motherboard, but above that it should work. You can contact me for some help regarding this question. I am an owner of b550 asrock.

Comment: Best option is to have a preinstalled windows 7 on other system and then just move your ssd to a new setup. Keep in mind that usb ports might (and probably wouldn't) work from the start, so consider getting a ps/2 mouse or keyboard beforehand.